# Gravity Form - Image Alignment

Tags: css, image, gravity

I have used images tags and titles to pull in some patterns used by our company for manufacture.  Thing is they don't look like the others in the gravity form.
I have used
Gravity Forms Color Picker Plugin to choose the coloured options so they all align and look great  (see image attached)[Colour Picker Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WE0fW.png)

but my image tagged ones are all in one long line [Patterned Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHAUc.png)

Is there any way to make my Patterns have the same layout in the gravity form front end as the colour options?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use grid to get the desired layout. If you want any help code-wise add your html and css code since we can't do much without it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi - there is no code for this.  It is a plugin Gravity Forms Color Picker and is just their standard layout which doesn't seem to be able to be changed.